# How to check is there any visible div with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML document and I want to check is there any visible div element with Jquery after page load.

After document ready function multiple div elements will be generated by some js function and I want to check these div elements generated or not.

I have found below code but it checks with ID but I don't have any ID;

```
 function checkContainer () {
    if($('#divID').is(':visible'))){
        createGrid();
    }else {
        setTimeout(checkContainer, 50);
    }
  }
```

Comment: So what do you have instead of `id`?

Comment: then use `div` since it is what you are looking for. just add parent in selector so that you will get the correct div

Comment: you can use `div` or add `class` while generating divs

Comment: share the generated html

Comment: @AdamAzad I only have type "Div".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to check is there any visible div element with JQuery

```
if ($("div:visible").length)
```

This will return true if at least 1 div is visible

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I specify div elements inside some main div? I mean like $("mainDivID.div:visible")

Comment: `$("#mainDivID.div:visible") ` Should do

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try searching for div instead of div Id:

```
function checkContainer () {
  if($("div").is(':visible'))){
    createGrid();
  }else {
    setTimeout(checkContainer, 50);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If any div, I think that's enough :

```
if($('div')){console.log('present');}
```